# How to change style.css with Qtranslate in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use qTranslate plugin to add language in my website with WordPress. 
I want to change style after selecting the language. How can I do this?

Comment: QTranslate ==> Bad choice. If I remember correctly it's not in development anymore...you should install Polylang

Answer (score 0):

First, the qTranslate has been replaced with a qTranslate-X plugin, so I suggest to use that one.

Check [this](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2017/05/qtranslate-x-customize-image-flags-language-menu/) article which is about the language flags for qTranslate-X. At the end of the article, it shows you how to use CSS for the flags.

The flags should have the `.language-chooser-item` class and active list item has `.active` class, so you would do something like this to set the CSS for the currently active flag:

```
.language-chooser-item.active a {
  ...
}
```